# Can the Powered Up Remote (latest train version) pair with the Boost Move Hub?

Tags: powered-up, boost

I've got the latest Powered Up remote, I was hoping it would pair with the Move Hub instead of using the Boost App.

At the moment it doesn't want to pair.

Answer (score 5):

Since June 2019, this is possible.  See here:
https://www.hispabrickmagazine.com/content/2019/06/03/powered-up-ii-powered-up-ii-networks/

Look right at the bottom of the article.

> The latest version of the Powered Up app (2.2.0) as well as the latest
>   version of the Boost app include new firmware for the Boost hub. After
>   this update it is possible to control the Boost hub with a remote
>   control.
>
> Establishing the connection is a little more difficult than connecting
>   a single Powered Up hub to a remote. It is not enough to just press
>   the start button on each device and wait. You need to press the start
>   button on both devices simultaneously after starting them to establish
>   the connection (as if the Boost hub were a second hub in an existing
>   network).
>
> Now you can control the internal motors (A and B in the Boost hub)
>   with the remote control.

Comment: Great answer! I'm glad that this is now possible. Thanks for sharing, and welcome to Bricks.SE!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible at the moment. This could be enabled in a future firmware update, but I'm honestly not sure how this would work. The Move Hub has 4 possible outputs. Mapping those to the pair of outputs normally controlled by the current remote seems like it would be somewhat clunky or non-intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

If you use third party software to form a Powered Up network you can pair the remote and the Move hub to a computer and control them both from there. You could write your program such that pressing the green button would change the LED colour and swap between controlling ports A/B or C/D.