# What is the procedure for connecting PoweredUp remote to Boost motor brick?

Tags: powered-up, boost

I have a PoweredUp remote from Passenger Train [60197](https://brickset.com/sets/60197-1/Passenger-Train) and the motor-brick from Boost Creative Toolbox [17101](https://brickset.com/sets/17101-1).

Sometimes I can connect the remote to the motor, sometimes I can't. When I do manage to connect the remote, sometimes it controls A and B (the main motors on the brick) sometimes it controls C and D (the external ports on the brick)

Is there a specific sequence of buttons to press to guarantee a connection and guarantee that it controls A and B?

[I have read about firmware](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/11360/can-the-powered-up-remote-latest-train-version-pair-with-the-boost-move-hub) updates and have connected both the remote and the brick to my phone using the Android PoweredUp app, but don't know how to tell if firmware updates are required.

Just to be clear the aim is to control the brick from the remote without using an Android phone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This video from Hispabrick magazine demonstrates it perfectly:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHv8or2GnFE

PRESS and RELEASE the green buttons on both devices and WAIT until they connect, the lights on the devices will match.
Lots of people have problems with this step, either they keep the buttons pressed (which will cause the devices to switch themselves off) or they don't have the patience to wait the couple of seconds until the devices connect and repress one of the buttons in which case the connection cycle restarts...

When connected there seem to be 3 modes:

- mode 1 controls A and B, i.e. the internal motors
- mode 2 controls B and A, i.e. the internal motors in reversed order
- mode 3 controls the external ports C and D, you can connect various motors, but also a train motor and external leds. The latter two don't operate in bang-bang mode (all on or all off) but you can set the speed/intensity gradually...
- There seems to be no mode where D and C or switched, or that an internal motor and external port are combined (e.g. "A and C" or "B and D")

You apparently cycle between the modes by shortly pressing (and releasing) the green button on both devices, the lights on the devices change (and match) when successful.

Regarding firmware updates, keep your app up to date on your Android device and it will automatically upload any firmware updates as soon as you connect a Powered Up device. You'll notice by the cycling colors the device displays while updating, it may take a few minutes,... It's a bad idea to interrupt any firmware update so please be patient.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and comprehensive answer!